# How to update specific property on array of object?

Tags: ember.js

Say "I initialized an array with predefined values like this" in my `controller`

```
  data: A([
    {
      lat: 14.5619175,
      lng: 121.0197196,
      title: "Jazz Mall",
      open: false
    },
    {
      lat: 14.5660656,
      lng: 121.0295681,
      title: "Avalue Residences",
      open: false
    },
    {
      lat: 14.5661493,
      lng: 121.0282417,
      title: "Century City",
      open: false
    }
  ])
```

Now, How can I update values to something like

`title: "Jazz Mall"` to `title: "Value has been change"`

Comment: Verify the answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: Hello @rinoldsimon

Since its emberjs

what works for me is by using set

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly then just by changing the value of the first array object would do this,

```
data.forEach((d) => {
  if (d.title === "Jazz Mall") {
    d.title = "Value has been changed"
  }
})
console.log(data);
```

Using ember set method

```
set(this.get('data').objectAt(index), 'prop', value)
```

Comment: You should use `set()` since the question is about ember.js or at least add a warning that you have to use `set()` if that property should be observed by framework and you aren't using tracked properties yet.

Comment: Using set works for me
`const temp_data = this.get("data");
`

`set(temp_data[index], "open", !value);
`